# WebSocket over HTTPS

Tags: websocket, certificate, ssl-certificate, iis-8, iis-8.5

I'm trying to use Websocket over HTTPS. Or just even get a Websocket handshake and connection without HTTPS with no success.

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro and installed the Websocket protocol.
I've created a web application in IIS with a self signed certificate.

When I'm running my website and invoking the connect websocket function I'm getting an 404 error in chrome dev tools under Network Tab-> Websocket.

I wrote the fqdn in the link to connect such as ws://fqdc/page.ashx
I also tried: ws://localhost/page.ashx

Can anyone suggest some idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved, I added

**HttpRuntime targetFramework="4.5**

under

**system.web** tag

and it worked.

I figure it out when looking into Event Viewer.

Comment: unmatched quotes. and please explain why this work? what do "httpruntimetargetframework" mean? what do you find in event viewer?

Comment: Because the project was compiled in .NET 4.5.1 and I got a message related to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self signed certificate, you must use it for the page as well and access through HTTPS, therefore the browser will prompt the user for the certificate acceptance.

Comment: OP say we get 404, which is different from a certificate failure.